# Google Sheets macro for printing

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I wrote the next macro, but isn't working.

For example: I have a button on the sheet (invoerblad) for printing, the button must print the sheet (Printblad), and when the print action is finished, it should return to the sheet (invoerblad).

```
function PrintSummary() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet().getName()
  var tempRange = ss.getSheetByName("Printblad").getRange(1,1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn());

  var bottomBuffer = 46;    // The amount of rows at the bottom of the sheet to ignore
  var rightBuffer = 4;         // The amount of rows at the right of the sheet to ignore
  var numRows = tempRange.getNumRows() - bottomBuffer;
  var numCols = tempRange.getNumColumns()  - rightBuffer;

  var range = ss.getSheetByName("Printblad").getRange(1,1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn());

  range.activate()

  // Run print operation
  // Options: Selection
  //                    No Gridlines
  // Paper Size:  A4
  // Layout:        Fit to Width
  //                    Landscape

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your are missing to use an API like [Google Cloud Printer](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/) to create and send a print job to your printer.

IMHO the details about this are far a way from the scope of this site. First read the docs then if you need further help consider to post your follow-up question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Google Cloud Print is not supported as of December 31, 2020.  Also, the “Save to Drive” option _won't be available for Windows, MacOS, and Linux devices_ but you can save documents to Google Drive from print preview. In terms of an equivalent to Cloud Print, Google suggests "printing with a printing partner", such as Directprint.io, LRS, NT-ware, PaperCut, Pharos, PrinterLogic, Printix, Y Soft. [Doc Ref](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9633006#zippy=%2Cprinting-partners)