# Creating a Button that allows you to Print a select area of cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, printing

I have a document here that I needed some help on!

**https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AFcHk-5JxMxj1ma-vTmCHIwBVn81Mgmxl001k__IMT4/edit#gid=0**

I'd like to create **multiple buttons in one tab** that, when pressed, allow the user to **print a select area of cells to a landscape 8.5 x 11 paper**. It would even be amazing if a prompt could appear simply confirming the number of copies the user wanted to print once they pressed the button...

I've tried searching through a number of forums but have gotten stuck trying to use their scripts. I know its inevitable to use scripting with this, so I wanted to see what your thoughts are with tackling this.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. The question needs more details and focus. Choose one of the scripts, show it (you might have to create a "minimal complete verifiable example") and tell use were exactly do you get stuck.

Comment: Related : https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/121533/88163

Comment: Hi. and welcome. _"I've tried searching through a number of forums but have gotten stuck trying to use their scripts."_ In order to answer your question, one needs to know what you've seen and rejected. Would you please list the main Q&As that you have tried.